# Split string in javascript by lines, preserving newlines?

Tags: javascript, regex, newline

How would I split a javascript string such as `foo\nbar\nbaz` to an array of lines, while preserving the newlines? I'd like to get `['foo\n', 'bar\n', 'baz']` as output;

I'm aware there are numerous possible answers - I'm just curious to find a stylish one.

With perl I'd use a [zero-width lookbehind assertion](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444): `split /(?<=\n)/`, but they are not supported in javascript regexs.

PS. Extra points for handling different line endings (at least `\r\n`) and handling the missing last newline (as in my example).

Comment: @Diodeus: valid argument. Fixing that right away.

Comment: There. Thanks again for reminding a casual user.

Comment: I posted a correct answer below, which works just the same as `/(?<=\n)/`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can perform a global match with this pattern: `/[^\n]+(?:\r?\n|$)/g`

It matches any non-newline character then matches an optional `\r` followed by `\n`, or the end of the string.

```
var input = "foo\r\n\nbar\nbaz";
var result = input.match(/[^\n]+(?:\r?\n|$)/g);
```

Result: `["foo\r\n", "bar\n", "baz"]`

Comment: A flaw: `'\n'.match(/[^\n]+(?:\r?\n|$)/g)` returns `null`

Comment: Also `'\r\r\r'.match(/[^\n]+(?:\r?\n|$)/g)` returns ['\r\r\r']

Comment: I think the regex should be: `/([^\r\n]*(?:\r?\n)|[^\r\n]+)/g`

Comment: The answer doesn't work, it skips blank lines.
@OlegMihailik's regexp doesn't allow \r in the middle of the line, and excludes those characters.

Answer (score 3):

how about this?

```
"foo\nbar\nbaz".split(/^/m);
```

*Result*

```
["foo
", "bar
", "baz"]
```

Comment: I like this approach, but I noticed it doesn't work as expected if the text contains "\r\n", example: `"foo\r\n\nbar\nbaz".split(/^/m);` gives:
`Array(5) [ "foo\r", "\n", "\n", "bar\n", "baz" ]`

Comment: Downside for me: you don't consistently get one array item per line. For example, `foo\n` is two lines but you get `["foo\n"]`. While regular split on line breaks gives: `[ "foo", "" ]`.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers and answers in comments are all flawed in different ways. I needed a function that works correctly on any string or file.

Here is a simple and correct answer:

```
function split_lines(s) {
    return s.match(/[^\n]*\n|[^\n]+/g);
}

input = "foo\r\n\nbar\n\r\nba\rz\r\r\r";

a = split_lines(input);

Array(5) [ "foo\r\n", "\n", "bar\n", "\r\n", "ba\rz\r\r\r" ]
```

It effectively splits at each newline `\n` but includes the `\n`, and includes a final line without trailing `\n` if and only if it is not empty. It includes all input characters in the output. We don't need any special treatment for `\r`.

I've tested this on a large chunk of random data, it does preserve all input characters, and `\n` only occur at the end of the lines.

Here's a test script:

```js
function split_lines(s) {
    return s.match(/[^\n]*\n|[^\n]+/g);
}

function gen_random_string(n, ncharset=256, nlprob=0.05, crprob=0.05) {
    var s = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        var r = Math.random();
        if (r < nlprob)
            s += "\n";
        else if (r < nlprob + crprob)
            s += "\r";
        else {
            var cc = Math.floor(r / (1 - nlprob - crprob) * ncharset);
            var c = String.fromCharCode(cc);
            s += c;
        }
    }
    return s;
}

function test(...args) {
    var s = gen_random_string(...args);
    console.log(`generated random string of length ${s.length} with args:`, ...args);

    var ok = true, ok1;
    var a = split_lines(s);
    console.log(`split into ${a.length} lines`);

    ok1 = s === a.join('');
    ok = ok && ok1;
    console.log("split lines combine to give the original string?", ok1 ? "OK" : "FAIL");
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        var s1 = a[i];
        ok1 = s1.endsWith("\n") || i == a.length-1;
        ok = ok && ok1;
        ok1 = !s1.slice(0, -1).includes("\n");
        ok = ok && ok1;
    }
    console.log("tested each line other than the last ends with \\n");
    console.log("tested each line does not contain \\n before the last character");
    console.log("Final result", ok ? "OK" : "FAIL");
}

test(10000, 256);
test(10000, 65536);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd stay away from `split` with regular expressions since IE has a failed implementation of it. Use `match` instead.

`"foo\nbar\nbaz".match(/^.*(\r?\n|$)/mg)`

Result: `["foo\n", "bar\n", "baz"]`

Comment: If \r occurs in the middle of a line, this excludes that character and splits at that point.

Answer (score 0):

One simple but crude method would be first to replace "\n"s with a 2 special characters. Split on the second one, and replace the first with "\n" after splitting. Not efficient and not elegant, but definitely works.